# reCAPTCHA centrally aligned

Tags: php, jquery, html, css, forms

[image: I have uploaded a photo of my problem]

I am very new to PHP! I have managed to get my reCAPTCHA box central to the page before the form is submitted, however once the form has been submitted the recaptcha box and form get shunted to the left while the results display centrally aligned.

Does anyone know how I can make sure that once the form has been submitted it doesn't move?

Sorry I am very new to PHP/CSS/HTML
This is my PHP HTML code for just the form

```
<div id="form">
<form method="post" action="niindex.php"><table>
<th><h2>I am searching for</h2><th>
<tr><td><select name="categories"><?php echo $str_options; ?></select></td></tr>
<br /> 
<tr><td><?php echo recaptcha_get_html($publickey); ?></td></tr>
<tr><td><input type="submit" id="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" /></td></tr>
</table></form>
```

and this is my CSS for the form:

```
#form{
font-family:"Century Gothic";
border:2px dotted #FFB6D7;
text-align:center;
display:inline-block;
padding-top:25px;
padding-bottom:25px;
padding-right:100px;
padding-left:100px;
```

}

Comment: That is some invalid HTML you have there. `th` needs to be in a `tr` and you can't have a `<br />` there. And what does the code you get back from `recaptcha_get_html` look like?

Comment: I have changed those errors, thank you! this still hasnt solved my problem of the box being shifted to the left once submitted

Answer (score 0):

Try this Style :-

```
<div class="captcha">
     Your Captcha code.
</div>

#recaptcha_area {
width: 440px;
margin: auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Pass like this :
`td{
    text-align:center; 
    vertical-align:middle;
}`

Answer (score 0):

1. place recapcha inside `<center></center>` tags

or
2.

```css
#recapchaPar {
  width: 500px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align:center;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}
```

```html
<div id="recapchaPar">
  123<!-- recapcha code here -->
</div>
```

or

3.

```css
#recapchaPar {
  width: 10vw;;
  margin: 0 45vw;/* 50vw - width of #recapchaPar/2 */
  text-align:center;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}
```

```html
<div id="recapchaPar">
  123<!-- recapcha code here -->
</div>
```